# disable exception handling in laravel test

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-testing

I've been trying to disable exception handling in my test so I can see the errors, but it's not working even if I intentionally break the code.

I'm just getting this generic response and it's not helping much.

```
Invalid JSON was returned from the route.
```

I've tried all solutions I can find online, but none of them is working.

I tried adding `$this->disableExceptionHandling()` at the top of the test method, it didn't work. I also tried the tutorial from Adam Wathan, (https://gist.github.com/adamwathan/125847c7e3f16b88fa33a9f8b42333da) that didn't work also.

I've even tried editing the Handler.php file

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    throw $exception;
    // return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

It's still now working.

Please how can I fix this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env`?

Comment: Yes. APP_DEBUG-true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in report method of handler.php

```
if (env('APP_ENV') === 'testing') {
    throw $exception;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 8 ( I think ) you can add the `$this->withoutExceptionHandling()` method to your tests and the exception will not get caught by the framework's handler. So you can:

```php
public function test_page()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
    $this->get('/');
    $this->assertSuccessful();
}
```

You could chain these all together if you wanted to.

[See the docs here.](https://%20https://laravel.com/docs/master/http-tests#exception-handling)